# Xcode Seemingly Unable to Use Arrays in C

Tags: c, arrays, xcode

It's very likely that this is user error as I'm somewhat new to Xcode, but I can't figure this out. Hopefully one of you can.

I'm trying to add an array using the following code:

```
int ArraySum (int MyArray [], int size) {
    int sum = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i< size; i++) {
        sum = sum + MyArray [i];
    }
    return sum;
}

int main (){
    int mynumberarray [6] = {1,2,3,4,5,6};
    int the_sum = ArraySum (mynumberarray, 6);
    printf ("The Sum is = %d \n", the_sum);
    return 0;
}
```

When I click the build & run button in Xcode, the only output I get is (lldb).

This would typically lead me to believe that I made a mistake somewhere, but when I run the code through Terminal it runs perfectly and gives me the correct sum.

Can anyone help me here? This isn't an isolated incident, I've had several issues working with arrays in Xcode that are working perfectly when executed in Terminal.

Screenshot:

[image]

Comment: I doubt this has to do with the *array* ...  code looks ok. (assuming you **have** `#include <stdio.h>` above)

Comment: your code is fine. compiles and runs on my gcc

Comment: @FelixPalmenThanks for the quick response. That's why I'm confused, the code is fine and runs in Terminal, but it won't run in XCode. Any idea why?

Comment: @ClsForCookies Thanks for the quick response. That's why I'm confused, the code is fine and runs in Terminal, but it won't run in XCode. Any idea why?

Comment: As I said, I very much doubt your problem has *anything* to do with the actual code. In the current state, I doubt someone can reproduce your problem. You could try to add more details (like your settings, where and how the "output" appears, whatever might help understanding the problem) and then hope someone who knows XCode has an explanation for you.

Comment: @FelixPalmen Thanks, I've added a screenshot so hopefully someone can help. Appreciate your input.

Comment: Looking at the screenshot, you do realise you have breakpoints set in your Xcode project, right ? What happens if you disable breakpoints and run ?

Comment: @PaulR That was exactly what I needed. Thanks!

Comment: Well at least you know how to use breakpoints for debugging now!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have breakpoints set in your Xcode project, so the program is pausing at the first breakpoint and giving you the `(lldb)` debugger prompt. Disable the breakpoints and run and everything should behave as expected. You can either manually disable each breakpoint (by clicking on it - it should then become dimmed), or go to `Debug` => `Disable Breakpoints` in the menu bar.

Comment: Ough, well spotted!